# How I can start minikube

Tags: command-line, kubernetes

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
on AWS cloud

```
Command 'start' not found, did you mean:

  command 'stars' from snap stars (2.7jrc3)
  command 'startx' from deb xinit (1.4.1-0ubuntu2)
  command 'stat' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'rstart' from deb x11-session-utils (7.7+4)
  command 'tart' from deb tart (3.10-1build1)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Comment: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Answer (score 3):

You must prefix all minikube commands with the word `minikube`, i.e. use `minikube start`. Check the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) (as stated in the [@changanauto](https://askubuntu.com/users/1210606/changanauto) comment).

Comment: kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
error: cluster "minikube" does not exist

Comment: @MayAlotaibi it's OK to get confused sometimes. I suggest going to YouTube and search for 'using minikube'. There is a lot of useful videos, both short and long. Happy kubing!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) ?

It is easy to install in any Linux

```
curl -Lo ./kind https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/dl/v0.14.0/kind-linux-amd64
chmod +x ./kind
sudo mv ./kind /usr/local/bin/kind
```

and you can create/delete clusters with simple commands:

```
kind create cluster
```

Once the cluster is created, you can check the context, so you can confirm which one is the name of your cluster, with:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                        CLUSTER                                                             AUTHINFO                                                            NAMESPACE
*         kind-kind                   kind-kind                                                           kind-kind
```

I know the right answer is the one provided by @Fjor, but is always nice to have other options :)

In AWS Cloud, I might suggest to use a AWS EKS service to get a most interesting challenge